# How to do a inner join with like condition in sql

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

Basically i have two tables and the two tables are EmployeeDetails and SalaryStatement are described below.

EmployeeDetails table:-

[image]

SalaryStatement table:-

[image]

I need to use the Employee_name field from EmployeeDetails table and see whether it is used in Operations field from SalaryStatement table. If the string "Name1" matches i need to do inner join from table1 and table2 considering all attributes from two tables. I am not sure how to use LIKE condition in inner join. Table 1 EmployeeDetails table is the base table here.

Comment: If you replace pictures with plain text I would try  to write query using your data example. Converting your pictures manually is too much work

Answer (score 2):

If you want the employee's name contained inside `Operations` then do this:

```
select *
from EmployeeDetails e inner join SalaryStatement s
on s.Operations like concat('%', e.EmployeeName, '%')
```

or maybe:

```
select *
from EmployeeDetails e inner join SalaryStatement s
on s.Operations like concat('%(', e.EmployeeName, ' ==%)%')
```

Comment: when i tried running the query i am getting error like Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: line 4:34 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%''. Currently the operation is performed in hive environment

Comment: @AKN If Hive does not support the operator LIKE in the ON clause then do a CROSS JOIN with a WHERE clause like this: `select *
from EmployeeDetails, SalaryStatement 
on SalaryStatement.Operations like concat('%(', EmployeeDetails.EmployeeName, ' ==%)%')`

Comment: Using like is taking too much of time. Is there any method to retrieve data faster.

Comment: If you want to check whether a substring is contained inside another string you use LIKE or INSTR which does not perform better than LIKE. So either use one of these options or redesign your dtabse so you don't need to use them.